# SSRS subreport adds blank pages IN BETWEEN the results of the data

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report that has a sub-report.

On my main report, the sub-report displays the headers and the data but the data is SPLIT by 2 blank pages when I do a PDF export of it. Everything is fine if I preview the report but when I save it as PDF, there are 2 blank pages in between the sub-report results.

The tablix for the sub-report is set to "keep together" and this has not helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this out. If the report is too wide, it'll put that blank space below each page of the report.

The fix was the make sure the width of the report was the right size.